# Reading data from a table using xpath which changes while loading the screen

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract data from a table by reading every row from the website.
I figured out that each line has almost the same xpath and can be distiguished by one number.
To read every line it is possible to iterate over the variable

```
line
```

in the following xpath

```
'//*[@id="app"]/main/main/section/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[' + str(line) + ']/a'
```

If there is a better solution for this, tell me :) but doing so leads to the following problem.

After line 14 some lines are skipped and line 20 is the maximum line which exists even though there are way more lines in that table on the website.

Probably the website does not load the whole table and thereore the information is not available.

I tried scolling the website while reading the lines. But the numbers between 1 and 20 are given to the new lines again which leads to the problem that it is not clear which numbers are linked to the new lines.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

Thank you and kind regards :)

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem but we won't be able to help you without at least the relevant HTML and better yet a link to the page. NOTE: The XPath you are using is going to be extremely brittle... break on the slightest change to the page because it's very long and uses a bunch of indexes, e.g. [1]. Once you post a link the page and the relevant HTML, we can help with that as well.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the `<table>` element.